# Android RecyclerView items expand on focus while scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-tv, leanback

I am trying to achieve an effect for my Android TV app so that views expand while they're focused.

I did that by animating the ViewHolder's main view's `LayoutParams`.

It works fine but the problem is that when i scroll towards the end of the view (Horizontal LinearLayout) the view expansion is not aligned with the end of the view, so it causes a really weird effect.

[image: RecyclerView strange scrolling]

Theres my code:

```
holder.m_view.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b)
                {
                    ResizeAnimation anim = new ResizeAnimation(view, 600, view.getWidth());
                    anim.setDuration(200);
                    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    view.startAnimation(anim);
                }
                else
                {
                    ResizeAnimation anim = new ResizeAnimation(view, 400, view.getWidth());
                    anim.setDuration(200);
                    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    view.startAnimation(anim);
                }

            }
        });
```

While `ResizeAnimation` is my own class who changes the view's `LayoutParams`.

How do I solve the strange scrolling problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Sadly no. I had to switch to using Android Leanback’s libraries, which takes care that the viewed item is always in the middle of the view, so this does not happen there

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the ViewHolder

```
itemView.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (hasFocus) {
                ViewCompat.animate(v).scaleX(1.12f).scaleY(1.12f).setDuration(30).translationZ(1).start();
            } else {
                ViewCompat.animate(v).scaleX(1.0f).scaleY(1.0f).setDuration(10).translationZ(0).start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I just need to set the white outline on the focused item.

```
holder.itemView.setOnFocusChangeListener { focusedView, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                focusedView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearlyt_gallery_item)                
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_imageview_focus)
            } else {
                focusedView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearlyt_gallery_item)
                    .setBackgroundResource(0)
            }
        }
```

//selector_imageview_focus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize="true">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/imageview_outline" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <padding android:left="@dimen/imageview_outline"
                android:top="@dimen/imageview_outline"
                android:right="@dimen/imageview_outline"
                android:bottom="@dimen/imageview_outline" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/imageview_outline" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <padding android:left="@dimen/imageview_outline"
                android:top="@dimen/imageview_outline"
                android:right="@dimen/imageview_outline"
                android:bottom="@dimen/imageview_outline" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/imageview_outline" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <padding android:left="@dimen/imageview_outline"
                android:top="@dimen/imageview_outline"
                android:right="@dimen/imageview_outline"
                android:bottom="@dimen/imageview_outline" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

// imageview_outline= 2dp

Answer (score 0):

**Add a this view  //activity view**

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Placeholder
```

to be center or desire position on of your screeen

Create **Listener interface** with `FocusSwapTo(v)`   method

add the call back interface      in  RecycleListAdapter

```
itemView.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (hasFocus) { 
           if(listerner!=null)
           listerner.FocusSwapTo(v)
            }
        });
```

//// main activity  implement callback

```
@override
public void FocusSwapTo(View view){
placeholder.setContentId(view.getId());    
}
```